# как устранить зависание GUI?

Tags: c++, qt, gui

Как я понял в qt основной цикл событий начинается после

```
int QApplication::exec()
```

соответственно `QMainWindow.show()` открывает окно только после того как выполнение всех задач после этого прекращается и `QApplication` возвращает число из `exec()`.
В обход этому в документации написано что можно использовать таймер с нулевым таймаутом что бы реализовать выполнение какого либо функционала после открытия окна.

> To make your application perform idle processing, i.e., executing a
>   special function whenever there are no pending events, use a QTimer
>   with 0 timeout. More advanced idle processing schemes can be achieved
>   using processEvents().

Проверил точкой остановой - все верно: `app.exec()` запускается перед функцией-слотом в таймере как и должно быть.
И все равно если после открытия окна к нему идет беспрерывное обращение (допустим бесконечный вывод в QPlainTextEdit какой-нибудь строки), то окно тупо не открывается, а сидит в доке свернутое. Если же на форму повесить кнопку при нажатии к которой происходит аналогичное обращение к любому виджету через `while (true){...}` то форма намертво зависает. Как избежать подобного и подружить GUI с любой нагрузкой, ну и если `ProcessEvent` в этом поможет, то объясните пожалуйста как его применить.

Цель: допустим в качестве приложения у меня консоль где бесконечно что то может выводиться и мне нужно видеть каждое изменение.

Comment: Вы не правы. Можно и до `exec()` создавать виджеты и с ними работать. А зависает у вас потому что: 1) большие вычисление в основном потоке, он же гуи поток, он же главный, тяжелые вычисления не рекомендуются -- приложение зависнет, т.к. менеджер окон не будет получать сообщения от Qt 2) Вызывайте в цикле http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents это поможет с зависением 3) всякие бесконечные циклы (и тяжелые вычисления) лучше перенести в отдельный поток, связав его сигналами с основным. По вашему примеру это будет отправка данных для добавления в QPlainTextEdit

Comment: Еще, забудьте про sleep и ему подобные функции для вызова в главном потоке -- гуи поток встанет и приложение не станет отвечать. Другое дело, что в отдельном потоке использование бесконечных циклов с sleep вполне нормальная вещи и проблем не вызовет. И если делать бесконечный цикл, то задержку в нем обязательно добавляйте, иначе это положет приложение -- процессор будет на полную загружен, а приложение заспамит самого себя

Answer (score 1):

Вынести вычисления в отдельный поток, тогда основной не будет блокироваться и зависаний не будет.